# OrientDB C# Update syntax

Tags: c#, orientdb

I am trying to recreate the OrientDB SQL query

```
UPDATE Car SET Name = 'Cadillac' WHERE Name = 'GM'
```

in the C# client OrientDB-NET.binary

What I have is

```
database
    .Update()
    .Class("Car")
    .Set("Name").Equals("Cadillac")
    .Where("Name").Equals("GM")
    .ToString();
```

but the SQL query this generates is

```
UPDATE Car WHERE  = 'GM'Name = 'Cadillac'
```

which is clearly not syntactically correct. What is the correct C# syntax for this query? Is this a bug in the C# client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
database
    .Update()
    .Class("Car")
    .Set("Name", "Cadillac")
    .Where("Name").Equals("GM")
    .ToString();
```